# C - incompatible types when assigning to type 'char *[(sizetype)(NColDataType)]' from type 'char *'

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, types, malloc

I am having trouble dynamically declaring a 2D array (one dimension of known size, the other not known until a file is read and the number of lines stored in the integer ·lines·).

```
int NColDataType = 16;
char *DataType[NColDataType];
DataType = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*lines);
```

When this is compiled, I receive the following error on the 3rd line:

> incompatible types when assigning to type 'char
>   *[(sizetype)(NColDataType)]' from type 'char *'

I am clueless as to what the issue is here, particularly as to why an error is thrown even though the types do seem to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `DataType` is an array of pointer, and you try to assign a pointer to it. I think you mean to do e.g.

```
DataType[0] = malloc(lines);
```

*Or* do you want `DataType` to be a pointer to an array, like

```
char (*DataType)[NColDataType];
DataType = malloc(sizeof(DataType[0]) * lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataType` is an array of pointers, you can't assign to it. Instead, assign to one of its elements, for instance, the first one:

```
DataType[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*lines);
```

Note that you don't need to cast the result value of `malloc`. `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`, so you don't need it. However, using it can be considered self-documented.